# Google Cloud Compute VM Instance for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, cloud, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

SORRY, THIS IS NOT A PROGRAMMING QUESTION.

I recently upgraded (before trial period expiry) my free google cloud trial account with micro VM instance hosting wordpress. I did not have any problem during the trial period, but once I have upgraded, I see database error - "Error establishing a database connection" almost all the time trying to open the webpage. I have to keep resetting (Stop & Start) my instance almost each time I want to connect to the website and view the homepage. I don't know what's gone wrong with it as nothing has changed in my simple skeletal website since the upgrade. 
Appreciate any help in giving me pointers to fix this problem.

Comment: This should be in [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 1):

With the limited data my guess is that based on this page [Google Machine Profiles](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types) the micro instance the cpu is not guaranteed so the request is timing out while it is waiting on the cpu to be available to make the connection... A theory.